# Como clicar num checkbox quando outro elemento obscura ele?

Tags: python, web-scraping, pynput

Estou escrevendo um código para automatizar alguns processos no site do SIAFI, não consegui fazer o Python clicar num checkbox, a não ser importando o pacote `pynput` e usando a função de posicionar o mouse com as coordenadas (x, y):

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
mouse = Controller()
```

Depois que eu importei usei o código abaixo para clicar exatamente neste local:

```
mouse.position (121,278)
```

O problema é que se eu usar esse script em um monitor diferente, tenho que modificar as coordenadas (x,y). Eu queria que o Python reconhecesse o campo do *checkbox* e clicasse nele, independente das coordenadas.

```
elemento11 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'formComp:tabelaPesquisarCompromissos:marcaTodas')))
elemento11 = browser.find_element_by_id('formComp:tabelaPesquisarCompromissos:marcaTodas')
mouse.position = (121, 278)#levar o mouse até a posição DEPENDENDO SE A PÁGINA FOR A ÚLTIMA PODE VARIAR
mouse.click(Button.left, 1)#clicar em selecionar todas
elemento12 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'formComp:botao_marcar_opcao_realizacao')))
time.sleep(int(segundos))
```

Abaixo vou descrever o código html da página web do siafi:

```
<input id="formComp:tabelaPesquisarCompromissos:marcaTodas" name="formComp:tabelaPesquisarCompromissos:marcaTodas" onclick="selecionarTodos(this);" type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou claro pra mim porque você não consegue clicar nesse checkbox. É por estar oculto ou porque só aparece baseado em outros checkboxes?

Uma solução que o time de QA encontrou no meu trablho, foi criar um método que fica verificando se o elemento está visível, para então executar algo.

Algo parecido com (to escrevendo da minha cabeça, não sei se funciona):

```
def esperar_por_elemento():
    tentativas = 0
    while tentativas < limite_de_tentativas:
    if browser.find_element_by_id()
        break
    sleep(ALGUM_TEMPO_PRA_ESPERAR)
    tentativas += 1
    return browser.find_element_by_id()
```

A idéia é mais ou menos essa.